# counting the number of lines between two characters

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I would like to count the number of the lines found between each two consecutive "*" characters including one of them. 
Input:

```
>*1
AA
BB
CC
>*2
RR
FGRE
>*3
A
```

output:

```
4 >*1
3 >*2
2 >*3
```

where the first field is the number of the lines between *'s and the second field is the string including them.

Comment: Why do you have all those tags?

Comment: Sorry! I was not sure what to use. Is it better now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/\*/{if (p) print c, p; p=$0;c=0} {c++} END{if (p) print c, p}' file
4 >*1
3 >*2
2 >*3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
cat  x1.txt | perl -ne '
  chomp;
  if ( $_ =~ /^>\*/ ) {
    $l1{$_}++;
  };
  $prev=$_;
  while(<>){
    chomp;
    if ( $_ =~ /^>\*/ ) {
       $prev=$_;
       $l1{$prev}++;
    } else { 
       $l1{$prev}++;}
    };             
    if (eof) {
      foreach $m1  ( keys %l1 ){
        print qq($m1 , $l1{"$m1"}\n);
      };
 };'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my command:

```
nl | sed -n '/*/p;/*/{1!p};$p' | xargs -n4 | awk '{print $3-$1, $2}'
```

Comment: Or `nl | sed -n '/*/{p;1!p};$p' | xargs -n4 | awk '{print $3-$1, $2}'`