# How to iteratively find number of lines between two patterns?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

This question is similar, but distinct from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39989376/how-to-determine-number-of-lines-between-two-strings-using-bash-and-standard-uti), [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295332/i-need-the-counts-of-lines-between-two-matching-patterns/295342), and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514752/counting-the-number-of-lines-between-two-characters).

Instead of pasting the lines in between the two patterns, I want to iteratively count the lines.

For example, given `file.txt` with these strings

```
abc
123
daafsd
asdfas
asdcasdfa
123
sdfasdc
asdfasdcasd
asdfasdfasdf
asdfasdfasdf
ascasdcasdcasd
123
asdcasdfacasdcas
123
asdfasdcasdcasc
asadfasdfas
123
```

I would want to count the lines between the pattern of `123`. So, the expected output would be:

```
3
5
1
2
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried

Comment: Does the last line always contain `123`?

Comment: `awk -v pat="123" '$0~pat{if (seen) print FNR-seen-1; seen=FNR}' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '$0=="123" {if (n) print NR-1-n; n=NR}' file
```

This uses the line number of matched lines to print the number of lines between them.

Comment: Very nice use of the implicit counter.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n)123(\n|$)' 'FNR>1 && NF{print NF}' Input_file
```

For shown samples, output will be as follows:

```
3
5
1
2
```

***Explanation:***

- In `awk` program setting `RS`(record separator) as `(^|\n)123(\n|$)`.
- Explanation of regex `(^|\n)123(\n|$)`: Setting record separator as 123(which can come at starting of line OR could be followed or start with a new line OR end with 123), as per shown samples.
- Then in main program checking condition if line number is greater than 1 AND `NF`(number of fields) is NOT zero then print the `NF`(total number of fields) for that line, which will be number of lines came between patterns.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and wc):

```
sed -En ':a;/123/{:b;n;//!{H;bb};x;s/.(.*)/echo "\1"|wc -l/ep;z;x;ba}' file
```

Turn on extended regexp `-E` and off implicit printing `-n`.

Match on `123`, fetch the next line, if it does not match, store the result in the hold space and repeat.

Within a substitution command, evaluate the result of the tail of the lines and count them using `wc -l`.

Clear the hold space, swap back to the pattern space and repeat.